# Function and their inverses

Tags: functions, inverse-function

How to find inverse function of $x+\sin x$.
(In this type of questions we equate this function with $y$ and then find $x$ in terms of $y$. How to solve this?)

Comment: The short answer is that you do not.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh yes, sorry. I will delete it

Comment: This is a good time to remind you that although we know certain functions to *exist*, that does not mean that they are easily expressible.  There are many examples of questions that although easy to pose and obvious that an answer must exist that are difficult or even impossible to answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz ohk sir.